# Determine whether or not $∀x[p(x) → q(x)]$ and $[∀xp(x)] → [∀xq(x)]$ are logically equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> Determine whether or not $∀x[p(x) → q(x)]$ and $[∀xp(x)] → [∀xq(x)]$ are logically equivalent.

I believe that they are not equivalent, but that is just an assumption. I am not sure how to go about proving this.

Comment: If they are not equivalent, then one can be true while the other is false, for some choice of $p$ and $q$. The first formula is false when you can find one $x$ such that $p(x)\wedge\neg q(x)$ is true. The second formula is false when $p(x)$ is true for all $x$, but $q(x)$ is false for some $x$. It is more likely for the second formula to be false than the second, so pick $p(x)$ to be some predicate which is true only part of the time ($x>0$), which will make the entire statement true, then pick $q(x)$ so that there is at least one $x$ such that $x>0 \to p(x)$ is false.

Comment: They're not equivalent, for the reasons that @CarlHeckman indicates. Think about the interpretations of $p$ and $q$ in a model. The former says that (the interpretation of) $p$ is a subset of $q$, a la "all men are mortal". The second says that if $p$ is the entire universe, then $q$ must be the entire universe. The first implies the second, but not conversely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ be the set of all $x$ where $p(x)$ is true.

Let $Q$ be the set of all $x$ where $q(x)$ is true.

Let $\Omega$ be the set of everything.

$\forall x ~ (px \implies qx)$ is equivalent to $P \subseteq Q$.

$(\forall x ~ px ) \implies (\forall x ~ qx)$ is equivalent to $P = \Omega \implies Q = \Omega$.

Can you think of possible sets $P$ and $Q$ where $P \subseteq Q$ is true and $P = \Omega \implies Q = \Omega$ is false?

Answer (score 1):

To Answer this, let us take two statements:

$p(x)=$ "Person who likes Mathematics"

$q(x)=$ "Person who like math.stackoverflow"

Equation 1:$ ∀x[p(x)→q(x)]$

It says "Its always the case that **if** a person likes Mathematics, they will like math.stackoverflow". It may be sometimes "**false**" as there may be some person who likes Mathematics but not Conclusion.

Equation 2: $[∀xp(x)]→[∀xq(x)]$

It says that "**If** its always the case that all person likes Mathematics then its always the case that they will like math.stackoverflow.
As Hypothesis cannot necessarily be always **true**, Equation 2 will always be **true**.

Answer (score 1):

Let domain be set of all natural numbers.

Let $p(x)$: $x$ is prime and $q(x)$ : $x$ is odd.

Here $\forall x [p(x) \implies q(x) ]$ is false because 2 is prime but not odd.
 While $\forall x p(x) \implies \forall x q(x) $ is true vacously as hypothesis is not true.